# How I can simplify my code to paste URL from data array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I've document includes these pieces of code:

A lil bit from `script setup`

```
const videos = ref([])

videos.value = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}/videos?api_key=85bdec956c0ccec9c74b7d51e525b938&language=en-US`).then(res => res.json())
console.log(videos.value.results[0].key)


const {
    key,
} = videos.value.results[0]



const frame1 = (`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videos.value.results[0].key}`)
const frame2 = (`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videos.value.results[1].key}`)
const frame3 = (`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videos.value.results[2].key}`)
const frame4 = (`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videos.value.results[3].key}`)
```

And lil bit from `template`

```
<div class="items-center grid grid-cols-2 gap-10  w-[100%] h-[100%] bg-gradient-to-t from-[rgb(45,45,45)] from-[-20%] via-slate-900 via-50% to-[rgb(45,45,45)] to-[100%] blur-0">
<iframe :src="frame1" class="w-[90%] h-[100%] border-2 m-5 mt-10 rounded-lg"></iframe>
<iframe :src="frame2" class="w-[90%] h-[100%] border-2 m-5 mt-10 rounded-lg"></iframe>
<iframe :src="frame3" class="w-[90%] h-[100%] border-2 m-5 mb-10 rounded-lg"></iframe>
<iframe :src="frame4" class="w-[90%] h-[100%] border-2 m-5 mb-10 rounded-lg"></iframe>
</div>
```

I tried many ways to write clearly code, but it would be good to get help on this question. And yes, I am quite new.

Comment: seems like a job for [v-for](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-for)

Comment: if the code works without error, then submit your question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'd better avoid top-level async; it is an [experimental feature yet](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html).

Secondly, watching changes and computing values ensures that the UI is always synced.

Thirdly, I assumed that the `movieId` is passed as a prop to extend the component's reusability.

```html
<template>
  <div
      class="items-center grid grid-cols-2 gap-10  w-[100%] h-[100%] bg-gradient-to-t from-[rgb(45,45,45)] from-[-20%] via-slate-900 via-50% to-[rgb(45,45,45)] to-[100%] blur-0"
  >
    <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>
    <iframe
        v-for="f in frames" :key="f"
        :src="f"
        class="w-[90%] h-[100%] border-2 m-5 mt-10 rounded-lg"
    ></iframe>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="js">

import { computed, ref, watch } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  movieId: {
    type: String,
    default: '150',
  },
});

const loading = ref(false);
const videos = ref([]);
const frames = computed(() => videos.value.map(x => `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${x.key}`));

watch(
    () => props.movieId,
    () => load(),
    {immediate: true});

async function load(movieId = props.movieId) {
  try {
    loading.value = true;
    const res = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}/videos?api_key=85bdec956c0ccec9c74b7d51e525b938&language=en-US`);
    videos.value = (await res.json())?.results || [];
  } finally {
    loading.value = false;
  }
}

</script>
```

Here, I used `watch` to track the prop value changes (it's optional). Also, by setting the `immediate: true` the watcher is triggered when the component is mounted.

Furthermore, I refactored the video list to keep only worthy values. Then, on every change in the video list values, the final frames are regenerated.

In the end, I simplify UI codes using a `v-for` loop to reflect changes in the model. By looking at the template, it is easy to understand that a frames list is provided by the script part without worrying about the length of URLs.